# Is it safe to bind password field to data object property in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This question is bugging me quite a bit.

Let's suppose I want to build a login component to use in my application (with Vue), where there are 2 expected input fields, one for the userID, the other for the password. Of particular concern in the context of this question is the password input field.

```
<input id="password" type="password" class="field-input">
```

I know you can do 2-way binding using v-model (and 1-way with v-bind), but the question is with password "should" you bind it to the data object in that way? Is it safe? Doesn't that mean the password is then stored in plain text in the data object? If that is not a safe way to do it then is there some other way?

Comment: If you actually know what the password is then it isn't safe at all. You should store only the hash and verify the password against it

Answer (score 2):

> With password "should" you bind it to the data object in that way?

Absolutely! According to the Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)

`Although a bit magical, v-model is essentially syntax sugar for updating data on user input events, plus special care for some edge cases ... v-model internally uses different properties and emits different events for different input elements - text and textarea elements use value property and input event`

Using the data function property below

```js
data() {
  return {
    password: '',
  }
}
```

Basically `<input type="password" v-model="password">` is a short form of
`<input type="password" v-bind:value="password" v-on:input="password = event.target.value">`

This is like telling the computer,

`on input (event), update the value of the password property.`

You are merely storing the password in memory which you would send via a form (I assume).

> Is it safe?

Absolutely! as long as you take other precautions such as using an input type of `password` (which you are) to prevent someone from snooping on the user's password as they type it, use HTTPS that will hash all details when going from client to server and as long as you use a POST request to send the password (via a form) with proper sanitisation (trimming the password value, escaping to reduce chances of injection attacks etc), proper validation (making passwords difficult to guess etc.), hashing (using bcrypt or any other hashing program) and storing the password on the server side (database) and some of the other best practices recommended by OWASP, you should be ok.

For more on OWASP authentication best practices, see [this] (https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html)

> Doesn't that mean the password is then stored in plain text in the data object?

It is stored in memory but hackers don't have access to it as long as you send it via a POST request in a well validated and sanitised form over HTTPS and using the other precautions stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can but it's best practice not to save password in client.

Use tokens. If you want some complexity and caveats, use JWT. But just use tokens. Like a list of securely generated bytes encoded as a string and then save that on that client as a cookie or `localStorage` and send that with all your requests.

When the user types in a username and password you hit you authorization API endpoint and if the credentials are good you create a session in your database and associate it to this secure token you made. When a request is made you can look up the session and make sure it’s still valid/not expired and you know what user it belongs to so they’re “authenticated.”

Also, Use HTTPS and read about authorization vs authentication.